# PySpark PartitionBy Timing out while writing S3 files

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, partition-by

Following code is trying to take a bunch of files from one input S3 path and then write them into individual S3 folders with folder name as a date column in the input data.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from datetime import date, datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from time import sleep
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

import os
import math
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--input", help="input s3 path")
parser.add_argument("--output", help="output s3 path")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.input:
    input = args.input
if args.output:
    output = args.output

sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
m1 = input

mrdd1 = sc.textFile(m1,use_unicode=False).map(lambda x: x.split('\t'))

fileSchema = {"fields":
[
{"metadata":{},"name":"col1","nullable": True,"type":"string","max_length":10},
{"metadata":{},"name":"col2","nullable": True,"type":"string","max_length":100},
{"metadata":{},"name":"col3","type":"string","nullable": True,"max_length":100},
{"metadata":{},"name":"col4","nullable": True,"type":"string","max_length":100,"date_mask":"yyyy-mm-dd"},
{"metadata":{},"name":"col5","nullable": True,"type":"string","max_length":100},
{"metadata":{},"name":"col6","nullable": True,"type":"string","max_length":100},
{"metadata":{},"name":"col7","nullable": True,"type":"string","max_length":100},
{"metadata":{},"name":"col8","nullable": True,"type":"string","max_length":100},
{"metadata":{},"name":"col9","nullable": True,"type":"string","max_length":100}
]}

def convertToDf( rdd, fileSchema ):
    schema=StructType.fromJson(fileSchema)
    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
    return df

monthlyrddtable1 = convertToDf(mrdd1, fileSchema)
newDf = monthlyrddtable1.withColumn("filename",concat(regexp_replace(col("col4"), "-", ""), lit(".txt.gz")))
newDf.write.save(path=output, mode="overwrite", format='csv', compression='gzip', sep='\t', partitionBy="filename")
```

The input files are 15MB each part files, and the total number of files are around 8000. Output is expected to write into 900 folders as 900 days are present. But the jobs are timing out or erroring out after running for 1 1/2 hours after S3 write failures. I am thinking the issue is due to writing too many small part S3 files. I am new to spark, is there any way I can set correct parameters for making this faster and avoid too many S3 files?

```
17/04/26 21:23:24 ERROR CSEMultipartUploadOutputStream: failed to upload object xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/ed=20130502.txt.gz/part-00017-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.csv.gz, trying to close piped
 input stream.
17/04/26 21:23:24 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
java.io.IOException: Error closing multipart upload
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.cse.CSEMultipartUploadOutputStream.close(CSEMultipartUploadOutputStream.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressorStream.close(CompressorStream.java:109)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat$LineRecordWriter.close(TextOutputFormat.java:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.close(CSVRelation.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1341)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: We encountered an internal error. Please try again. (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: 
InternalError; Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx), S3 Extended Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.cse.CSEMultipartUploadOutputStream$3.run(CSEMultipartUploadOutputStream.java:155)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: We encountered an internal error. Please try again. (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: InternalError; Request ID: X
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx), S3 Extended Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$CompleteMultipartUploadHandler.doEndElement(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:1698)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.AbstractHandler.endElement(AbstractHandler.java:52)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Wondering were you able to resolve this?